AuthenticationFailed while trying to connect to mongo docker container
I'm trying to connect to a Mongo container but I keep getting an authentication error.

docker-compose.yaml
mongo:
image: mongo:latest
container_name: mongo
hostname: mongo
command: [--auth]
env_file: .env
volumes:
  - ./docker/mongo-seed/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
restart: always
ports:
  - "27017:27017"

.env file
MONGO_DATABASE_NAME=app-local
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://{0}:{1}@localhost:27017
MONGO_USER=user-local
MONGO_PASSWORD=pwd-local

script inicial 001_initial_script.js
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin")

db.createUser({
    user: process.env["MONGO_USER"],
    pwd: process.env["MONGO_PASSWORD"],
    roles: [
        {
            role: 'dbOwner',
            db: process.env["MONGO_DATABASE_NAME"],
        },
    ],
});

db = db.getSiblingDB(process.env["MONGO_DATABASE_NAME"])


Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

You created the user in admin database, thus you must connect with
--authenticationDatabase admin

not with --authenticationDatabase app-local
Apart from that, authentication becomes active only if you have created an admin user, i.e. a user with root role or at least userAdminAnyDatabase role. I am not familiar with docker, I don't know if such a user is created already in your case.
Then, I don't think it is smart to overwrite internal and pre-defined db variable. Better use on of these:
db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser(...)

use admin
db.createUser(...)

const admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
admin.createUser(...)

